# How do I set up Google Play Game services with a native-glue NDK app?

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play-games

I have a pure NDK/C++ app which I'm integrating with Google Play Games (from here on referred to as GPG) services. 
According to the android_support.h file coming with GPG, I have to merge my Java code with Native code like shown below. However as I'm using native-glue, I have no java code at all, neither do I have any activity extend. Does anyone know if it is possible to use GPG with Android NDK while using native-glue? Or do I have to extend my project with a Java activity?

```
// Java
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onActivityResult(int req, int res, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  nativeOnActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
 private static native void nativeOnActivityResult(
  Activity activity, int requestCode,
  int resultCode, Intent data
 );
}

// C++.
void Java_com_example_yourapp_YourActivity_nativeOnActivityResult(
 JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz,jobject activity,
 jint request_code, jint result_code, jobject data
) {
 gpg::AndroidSupport::OnActivityResult(env, activity, req, res, data);
}
```

Comment: Look to extend `NativeActivity` which is the Java activity (provided by the platform) which calls your native C++ code.  See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity

Comment: Ah thanks, so I have to add a Java class/file to the project I suppose?

Comment: Probably - never done this so I can't really answer the question.

Comment: Ah well, I felt so free without any java, guess I have to add that then.